# issues in table reading from MS Access using ODBC

Tags: qgis, ms-access, odbc

I want to add two tables from my MS Access db.
So I follow the procedure to add ODBC (add vector layer, database, etc.) and it works.
I choose the tables that I want to add and hit ok.
Qgis adds both the tables I chose, BUT are showed in a different way.
In the first table I’m not able to see any data, just the name of the fields.
In the second one I see everything.

[image]

Somebody can explain to me if I’m doing something wrong?